# How to prevent capacitive discharge on my load after MOSFET off state

Tags: mosfet, load, capacitive

I built a button on off latch circuit using nand Gates then connected latched output to Nmosfet's gate with a resistor. My load is a smps circuit drives the power Led and this circuit has emc filter stage that contains capacitors and inductors. My load takes place between Vcc and MOSFET drain and source connected to ground. My Led must work stabil between 18-36 volts. While low voltages below the 24volts Led working well but as the voltage increase when i turned off button, Led opens instantaneously after it close. At low voltages my smps Led circuit draws little bit more currents and no discarge happens. But as the voltages increase current dicrease and instant on state happens. CAN u help me to prevent this problem guys.Here is my circuit that i draw pmosfet to see are there any diffrence or not with pmos. But same thing happend. Let me inform photo is clear or not.
[image]

Comment: Post you circuit, its hard to make sense of your post without it.

Comment: I added p MOSFET type. N MOSFET drawing at work. But same problem is here also.

Comment: Please fix that picture, it's all whitespace and not that useful

Comment: I hoped by fixing the *link* the image would open with better resolution in a new browser window, but alas. Please add a bigger picture / picture with better resolution.

Comment: Okey sent from mobile. Im gonna handle tomorrow morning on my pc. I have been trying to fix this problem for two weeks, also my sample gonna send to the customer  at friday. :|

Comment: Guys i uploaded  my circuit please help me  @VoltageSpike

Comment: Crop police here. I edited your post and cropped your schematic.

Comment: Are there anyone have any idea to fix my problem ?